# tfs replication of servers in two countries

Tags: tfs

We have a dev team in asia with tfs and one in US.  We would like to have another tfs in US and sync both of them in real time. Each of them can serve as the fail over cluster for each other.

Going forward we want to have teams login to respective server.
How can we achieve replication in real time ?. How does merge and collision be dealt with?.
We have proxy already but we want something better than that.

Comment: Have you considered moving to Visual Studio Team Services?

Comment: But wouldnt we need to host it elsewhere?. We dont want to host it elsewhere.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't replicate TFS in real time. You need to backup database and restore it on another server to have full migration. Or use tools like TFS Integration Tool to migrate work items or changesets (data lossy migration).

Using [Visual Studio Team Service](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs.aspx) maybe a good option for your scenario. Visual Studio Team Services provides a set of cloud-powered collaboration tools  that work with your existing IDE or editor, it's not needed to set up on-premise TFS.

Comment: We dont want the tfs to be hosted somewhere. We are managing the server currently in house. Can we have Tfs server A and B, exist in a domain and be in sync with each other through a cron job or something like that?.

Comment: No, this is not a supported scenario in TFS out of the box. You can use TFS Integration Tool or other tools to migrate part of data in TFS.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT is there anyway we can pre-cache complete TFS collection on a TFS proxy? 
We have deployed TFS proxy at remote location but it shows no effect at all. The download speed is still super slow.

Answer (score 0):

Get database guy in the picture and ask him how to replicate and sync DB severs. Source code and change sets are stored on SQL. This should help you to proceed further.

Comment: I have two tfs servers A and B. People checkin code to A and B simultaneously. I want B to merge changes in B + A. Im not sure if replication will solve this problem if B is also changing because there needs to be some conflict/merge resolution involved.